# Eclipse no me funciona

Tags: java

Uso eclipse luna para programar en java, lo tengo instalado, y puedo abrirlo bien, pero cuando estoy en una clase de JFrame y edito el codigo, cada vez que lo edito me aparece lo siguente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

entro al codigo, pero no tiene errores. Cierro eclipse, y cuando lo vuelvo a abrir me funciona perfecto, hasta que vuelvo a editar el codigo, y tengo que volver a cerrarlo. Se me hace dificil trabajr asi y no se que le puede estar pasando, lo instale de la pagina que nos mando mi profesora y de la manera que nos dijo, instale tambien java antes, etc.

Comment: Le diste clean and build?

Comment: Parece ser un problema con la herramienta Window Builder del Eclipse. Quizás el código generado/modificado para el JFrame no puede ser actualizado en ese momento debido al error que te muestra allí.